# Get openfire chatroom settings on create

Tags: java, plugins, handler, openfire

I have a plugin with a handler on chatroom creating.
When I create a new room with specified maxUsers (doesn't matter from admin panel or rest api plugin) I get maxUsers = 30.

```java
public void roomCreated(room jid) {
   // ...
   MUCRoom mucRoom = XMPPServer.getInstance()
      .getMultiUserChatManager()
      .getMultiUserChatService(room)
      .getChatRoom(room.getNode());
   // ...
   int maxUsers = mucRoom.getMaxUsers(); // always 30 in this handler
   // ...
}
```

For example in handler on changing room settings, maxUsers is correct.

Are the `roomCreated` handler be called before the chatroom settings set?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

It's enough to run code in a Thread with a little (100-200 ms) delay ad beginning.

It might not the best solution, but wrong max users value on room created is not a good too.